# pyserial working on spyder but not on command line

Tags: python-2.7, pyserial

I wanted to install pyserial for python 2.7 version. However, when I write `python -m pip install pyserial` or `conda install pyserial` or `conda install -c conda-forge pyserial` on my command line I encounter the error as shown in the Image below.

[image: Error shown on cmd line]

Interestingly `import serial` works on Spyder.

When I run a python code from my terminal I get an error:

> No such module: serial

Please help.

I used `sudo`, also. This is what I get when I run `import serial` in Python.
[After using Sudo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Ixe.png)

Comment: Do it with `sudo`?

Comment: I did it using sudo as well. Still I am getting the same error. I have edited my answer to include another screen shot. Please see. Thank You.

Comment: Try to uninstall it and install again. Also, why you don't install this package from the repo (as it seems you are using Ubuntu)? Like `sudo apt-get install python-serial`